# How to calculate the daily late fee?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Due to my ignorance, I owe the mobile service provider **$701**. The penalty is **3%** per day.

That means on day 1, I should pay

> $701 + 701\times0.003$

On day 2, I should pay

> $701 + 701\times0.003 + (701 + 701\times0.003) \times 0.003$

and so on.

I learned a lesson that I should pay every bill as soon as possible. I also want to lean some math here:

1. How to calculate the fee until a certain day, say 40 days later?
2. What's the amount of the penalty fee till that day?

Comment: Over the course of $n$ days you pay back $701(1.003^{n})$.

Comment: I'm guessing this is actually a problem on a homework assignment, rather than your actual situation, in which case the question is, have you no simlar problem in your course materials? Alternatively, if you expand that parenthesis, and write things out for days 3 and 4, you may see the pattern. You may even figure out how to sum it, if you know about geometric series.

Comment: @Autolatry You got the factor wrong. It's $3$ per mille, not $3$ per centum.

Comment: @AlexR thanks, edited.

Comment: @Autolatry Thank you. I'm poor at math. I'll try to figure out how to reach this formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a bill from ChinaMobile. I have no homework, and I'm poor at math. Thank you for mentioning **geometric series**. I should learn that first.